# Angular 8 catch output events of video in iframe (play, pause, end)

Tags: iframe, angular8

I have an iframe in my angular application to which I pass the url of a video as [src].
This is the code for the iframe:

```
            <iframe id="videoId" name="videoName"
              title="video player" class="video-player video-player-responsive" type="text/html" width="100%"
              height="100%" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen allowTransparency="true"
              [src]="element.value.url +'&GAOn=true&GAProgressInterval=25'| safe"
              style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"></iframe>
```

I want to catch the output events of play, stop and end.
I've tried this way, adding the outputs for onplaying, on pause, onended:

```
            <iframe id="videoId" name="videoName"
              title="video player" class="video-player video-player-responsive" type="text/html" width="100%"
              height="100%" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen allowTransparency="true"
              [src]="element.value.url +'&GAOn=true&GAProgressInterval=25'| safe"
              style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" (onplaying)="handleVideoPlayEvent($event)"
              (onpause)="handleVideoPauseEvent($event)" (onended)="handleVideoEndEvent($event)"></iframe>
```

But the methods are not called. I've also tried with (play), (pause) and (ended) but it doesn't work.